# android notification launches same activity twice

Tags: android, android-notifications

When I click the notification on the status bar it launches an activity but the behavior is strange. If my app is in foreground and I click the notification the notification intent is fired once. If my app is in background then the notification intent is fired twice. If I exit the app (ie all activities have been popped by hitting the back button) then  notification intent is fired once. Can anyone explain this behaviour. The code snippet is as follows:

```
_notification = new Notification(icon_id, "Ticker Text", System.currentTimeMillis());
_showActivityIntent = new Intent();
_showActivityIntent.setAction(MyActivityName);
_showActivityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK + Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
_showActivityPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, _showActivityIntent, 0);
_notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "My title", "My text", _showActivityPendingIntent);
_notificationMgr.notify(notificationId, _notification);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
_showActivityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Try this. it will prevent multiple instances of the same activity. u can put this in the manifest also

Comment: I'll try it out, but can you explain why the same activity is being launched twice ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#acttask . if you read the documentation it clearly says what every flag does.

Comment: But why are the 2 being launched in the first place. This seems like a work around, not a fix.

Comment: This not a workaround. They are launched twice because that is the default behavior. You can create multiple intents and have multiple instances of the same activityclass. And thats not what is needed, then the flags are there to help. Read through how processes and back stacks work - http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Answer (score 0):

None of the flags worked:

```
  Intent().apply {
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            ...
```

You need to add in the Manifest for that activity:

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
android:taskAffinity=""
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

Check: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/navigation